# Create triangular slider with java

Tags: java, android, user-interface, geometry

I'm trying to make a slider like this.
[Triangular slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4jQl.png)
I can figure out how to make the triangle, but the functionality such as dragging the node, bounding its location to within the triangle and determining values based on the node coordinates are beyond me right now.

I have looked online but i'm not sure what to call this exactly, so researching it is proving difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here have some my thinking that you can refer to:

- the first step is to create a triangle.
- the second step is to create a node within the triangle.
- the third step is to make the node can be dragged, with node dragging
  you should calculate the distance between the node and three
  vertices, and make an appropriate adjustment for your purpose
  proportion.

Maybe these functionalities are difficult for you. but you will grow up a lot when you figure out those troubles. hope everything goes well with you.

Comment: Yes thanks a lot i agree i will. You have typed everything i know. im practising now. Thanks for the input it lets me know im on the right track.